# How to memoize all instances of a class without repeated code?

Tags: ruby, memoization

I'm using [Memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) and I have a specific case where all the methods of my class need to be memoized. I would like to be able to memoize them without the need to write the `memoize :instance_method_name` for each method. I would like to do something like:

```
class MyClass
  extend Memoist

  def initialize
    instance_methods(false).each(&:memoize)
  end

  private

  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end

  def method3
  end
end
```

But of course it does not work because `instance_methods` is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the methods on the correct object:

```ruby
class MyClass
  extend Memoist

  private

  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end

  def method3
  end

  instance_methods(false).each(&method(:memoize))
end
```

[`Module#instance_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) is an instance method of the [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html) class, not an instance method of the `MyClass` class. Therefore, you need to call it on an instance of `Module`, not on an instance of `MyClass`.

Likewise, you are calling [`Memoist#memoize`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/memoist/Memoist:memoize) on an instance of [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html), but you need to call it on an instance of [`Memoist`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/memoist/Memoist) instead, i.e. in this case on `MyClass`.

Note that even if the code you wrote did work, it wouldn't do what you think it does. `memoize` works by replacing the method with a new method that wraps and caches the old method. However, if your code worked the way you wanted it to, *every time* you create a new object, it would have called `memoize` *again*, and thus wrapped the already wrapped method, and then wrapped the wrapper of the already wrapped method, and then wrapped the wrapper of the wrapper of the already wrapped method, and so on.

Comment: `each(&:memoize)` would call `memoize` on an instance of  `Symbol` maybe you were going for `each(&method(:memoize))`?

Comment: Thanks. I blindly copied that from the OP.